# Different way of accessing array elements in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am a teaching assistant for a C programming course, and I came across the following line of C code:

```
char str[] = "My cat's name is Wiggles.";
printf("%c %c %c %c\n", str[5], *(str + 5), *(5 + str), 5[str]);
```

I never came across the very last argument (`5[str]`) before, and neither did my professor. I don't think it's mentioned in K&R and C Primer Plus. I found this piece of code in a set of technical interview questions. Does anyone know why C allows you to access an array element that way also? I never heard of an index being outside the set of brackets and the name of an array inside the brackets.

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is a beaten-to-death FAQ. http://c-faq.com/aryptr/joke.html. Actually, the example you posted in your question contains the answer already.

Comment: Yes, array indexing is commutative.  Rarely seen outside of IOCCC entries.  If seen in production code, shoot the author on sight.

Answer (score 15):

Perfectly valid C. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Arrays):

> Similarly, since the expression a[i] is semantically equivalent to *(a+i), which in turn is equivalent to *(i+a), the expression can also be written as i[a] (although this form is rarely used).

Wacky, but valid.

Answer (score 5):

`str[5]` directly translates to `*(str + 5)`, and `5[str]` directly translates to `*(5 + str)`. Same thing =)

Answer (score 4):

It's basically just the way C works.  `str[5]` is really equivelent to `*(str + 5)`.  Since `str + 5` and `5 + str` are the same, this means that you can also do `*(5 + str)`, or `5[str]`.

It helps if you don't think of "5" as an index, but rather just that addition in C is [commutative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutativity).

Answer (score 2):

> Similarly, since the expression a[i] is semantically equivalent to *(a+i), which in turn is equivalent to *(i+a), the expression can also be written as i[a] (although this form is rarely used).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Accessing_elements

Answer (score 2):

Its all same. *ptr or ptr[0] actually means *(ptr+0). So whenever you write *ptr or ptr[0] it goes as   *(ptr+0). Let say you want value at ptr[4] so it means you can also write it as *(ptr+4). Now whether you write it as *(ptr+4) or *(4+ptr), it's same. so just for understading if you can write *(ptr+4) as ptr[4] same way *(4+ptr) is same as 4[ptr]. Please go through http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Accessing_elements for more details.

Answer (score 2):

if str is an array of type char, then we can access any index say i as below-

1. str[i]
2. *(str + i)
3. char *p = str, then access the index i as p[i] or *(p+i)

Answer (score 1):

It's a funky syntax for sure, but...

`str[5]` would mean `*(str+5)`

And

`5[str]` would mean `*(5+str)`

Answer (score 0):

Example Code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
    for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i++){
        printf("%d\t", i[arr]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:1       2       3