# Fastest format to print an array

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num[]={24, 34, 12, 44, 56, 17},i;
    for(i=0;i<=5;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",i[num]);
        printf("%d\n",num[i]);
        printf("%d\n",*(num+i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

// Are all three formats allowed in `C` to print an array and which is the fastest one?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546075/different-way-of-accessing-array-elements-in-c

Comment: Forget about it. printf is slow in general.

Comment: which compiler produce slower result for one of those?

Comment: Performance of all of them are similar .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All are same

```
num[i] = *(num + i) = i[num]
```

When it comes to which is faster the compiler performs the same operation in all the cases so it is same.

Comment: worth adding that this is due to a compiler seeing  them in exactly the same way (as pointers to the int).

Comment: @sam Not in any decent compiler.

Comment: @sam Absolutely not, because all three are literally the same thing. The only difference is more or less syntactic sugar.

Comment: And compared to the overhead of calling `printf()`, it doesn't matter anyway.  You might as well ask, "Which cup adds more water to this giant swimming pool?"

Comment: @AndrewHenle More like "Which cup adds more water to this world ocean"?

Comment: @andrew But isn't it true that accessing array elements by pointers is always faster than accessing them by subscripts?

Comment: @sam You need to understand that the notation `num[i]` is being treated as a pointer operation.(you are reading some memory location)

Comment: @Magisch *More like "Which cup adds more water to this world ocean"?*  `printf()` isn't *that* slow.  Do you mean C++ streams?  ;)

Answer (score 4):

All 3 cases are allowed, because the `num[i]` is just ["syntactic sugar"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for the less readable form `*(num+i)`.

This is guaranteed by the standard 6.5.2.1:

> The definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is
>   identical to (*((E1)+(E2)))

So what your 3 cases boil down to is:

- `*(i + num)`
- `*(num + i)`
- `*(num + i)`

The order of the operators of the `+` operator doesn't affect performance so they are all 100% equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

Modern compilers will optimise all three to the fastest method. This might be something entirely different.

Besides, the *bottleneck* here is going to be in the stringification of the integral value and the buffering to the OS.

`i[num]`: I trust you wouldn't do that in practice.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case the answers so far haven't convinced you that all three approaches are identical, heres the assembler code for a similar case. Replacing the printf with simple assignments to simplify things.

Taking the C code:

```
 int main()
 {
     int num[]={24, 34, 12, 44, 56, 17},i;
     int dst[]={0,0,0,0,0,0};
     int dst1[]={0,0,0,0,0,0};
     int dst2[]={0,0,0,0,0,0};

     for(i = 0; i <=5; i++)
     {
         dst[0] = i[num];
         dst1[0] = num[i];
         dst2[0] = *(num+i);
     }

     return 0;
 }
```

Compiling this:

> gcc test.c -o test.out

And view the assembly with otool (OSX)

> otool -tV test.out

After stripping out the unrelated stuff, the lines of assembly corresponding to our 3 assignments:

```
@ For loop
0000000100000ed0    cmpl    $0x5, -0x88(%rbp)
0000000100000eda    jg  0x100000f20

@  dst[0] = i[num];
0000000100000ee0    movslq  -0x88(%rbp), %rax
0000000100000ee7    movl    -0x20(%rbp,%rax,4), %ecx
0000000100000eeb    movl    %ecx, -0x40(%rbp)

@ dst1[0] = num[i];
0000000100000eee    movslq  -0x88(%rbp), %rax
0000000100000ef5    movl    -0x20(%rbp,%rax,4), %ecx
0000000100000ef9    movl    %ecx, -0x60(%rbp)

@ dst2[0] = *(num+i);      
0000000100000efc    movslq  -0x88(%rbp), %rax
0000000100000f03    movl    -0x20(%rbp,%rax,4), %ecx
0000000100000f07    movl    %ecx, -0x80(%rbp)

@ For loop
0000000100000f0a    movl    -0x88(%rbp), %eax
0000000100000f10    addl    $0x1, %eax
0000000100000f15    movl    %eax, -0x88(%rbp)
0000000100000f1b    jmp 0x100000ed0
```

So you can see, the compiler treats all the operations in exactly the same manner, they are translated to identical assembler instructions, and so would take the same amount of time.

Comment: In general, it is meaningless to inspect assembly output for un-optimized code.

Comment: The point is that the compiler treats each operation in exactly the same way, i assume that would hold during the optimization step - i.e. each operation would be optimized in the same manner, and therefore take the same amount of time.