# Indexing an integer

Tags: c, type-conversion

i'm fairly new to programming, so have mercy on my unknowing soul ;)

I've found following code, which i don't really understand:

```
void main(void)
{
   char a[]="0123456";
   int i=5;

   printf("%c\n", a[i]);
   printf("%c\n", i[a]);
}
```

Now my question: why does the last line even work? Indexing and integer should, as far as i know, not even work? I guess it has something to do with the output being set to char.

Could somebody please explain this to me?

Thanks,
redscale

Comment: Where did you 'find' the code?   It's a well-known mega-dupe on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5546075/7761980

Comment: Found it in some old tests from university. Looking at the explanation, it is very obvious. Still have to wrap my head around all this little details.