# An unusual cpp array expression 2[1[a]]

Tags: c++, arrays

Here is the code:

```cpp
        int a[2][4] = {
            {3,   6,  9, 12},
            {15, 18, 21, 24}
        };
        std::cout << 2[1[a]] <<std::endl;
```

the output is `21`, which means `2[1[a]]` is equal to the expression `a[1][2]`.

I also try other expressions, and the result is same. `num2[num1[a]]` is equal to `a[num1][num2]` .

My question is, which book or reference says it works?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546075/different-way-of-accessing-array-elements-in-c

Comment: Which book or reference says it works?   The C++ standard is the authoritative definition of C++ - the purpose of the standard is defining the basis for assessing correctness of implementations (i.e. compilers and standard libraries).   For example, the 1998 C++ standard is the yardstick against which correctness of C++98 implementations are assessed,  the 2017 C++ standard is the yardstick against which correctness of C++17 implementations are assessed.